# Matching a list (of tags) with another and detecting presence of common elements

Tags: drools, drools-planner

My requirement is to match tags. In the example, this particular `HourConstraint`  checks the `TeacherHour` assigned to `Hour(23)`.

Specifically,  it checks `TeacherHour.attributes["tags"]` for the values `["asst_ct","teacher_john_smith"]` and **detects atleast one match**, two in this case (both `"asst_ct"` and `"teacher_john_smith"`) .

```
TeacherHour:
  id: 47
  assigned_hour: Null
  attributes:Map<List<String>>
    "tags":["asst_ct","no_strenuous_duties","kinda_boring","teacher_john_smith"]
    "another_attribute":[...]

HourConstraint:
   hour: Hour(23)
   attribute: "tags"
   values_list: ["asst_ct","teacher_john_smith"]
```

---

**Question:** How do I detect the presence (true or false) of **common elements** between two lists?

Drools Expert has `memberOf` and `contains`, but they check a scalar vs a collection, never a collection vs a collection.

I see two potential ways:

1. introduce a function `boolean isIntersecting(list,list)` and tell Drools to use that for truth checking
2. Implement `TeacherHour.attributes[]` as a string instead of a list and `HourConstraint.valueslist` as a regular expression that can match that list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options. Most straight forward is to use the Collections class to do that for you:

```
rule X
when
    $t: TeacherHour( )
    HourConstraint( Collections.disjoint( $t.attributes["tags"], values_list ) == false )
...
```

If this is something you would use often in your rules, then I recommend wrapping that function in a pluggable operator, supported by Drools. Lets say you name the operator "intersect", you can then write your rules like this:

```
rule X
when
    $t: TeacherHour( )
    HourConstraint( values_list intersect $t.attributes["tags"] )
...
```

A third option, is to use "from", but that is less efficient in runtime as it causes iterations on the first list:

```
rule X
when
    $t: TeacherHour( )
    $tag : String() from $t.attributes["tags"]
    exists( HourConstraint( values_list contains $tag ) )
...
```

Comment: I would go with Collections.disjoint. Should I rather use a set datatype? Also could you refer me to "pluggable operator"?

Comment: Try this: http://blog.athico.com/2010/06/creating-pluggable-oprators.html . Or copy&paste this class adapting it to your needs: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/base/evaluators/MatchesEvaluatorsDefinition.java