# how can I get dynamic property in drools

Tags: java, drools

I have a XML file containing metadata like a field's maximum length. I have to use drools to build rules to validate this metadata against a list of facts. I don't want to hardcode the name of each field that may or may not be specified in the XML.

I tried to do this :

```
when
   $metadata: Metadata(maxLength != null);
   $obj: Object(eval($metadata.getFieldName()).length > $metadata.maxLength);
then
   // TODO
end
```

It does not work and I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors while building rules : Unable
to Analyse Expression $metadata.getFieldName() > $metadata.maxLength:
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class
java.lang.String and class java.lang.Integer] [Near : {...
$metadata.getFieldName() > $metadata.maxLength ....}]
```

Is it possible to dynamically get a field name and compare its maximum length? Will I have to create a java object to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have decided to generate my drools file dynamically from my XML using rule templates.

Answer (score 0):

You talk of XML and metadata. Can you distinguish all entities? For example, if it is about orders, can you extract each order, and attributes of each order?

I solved a similar problem with using **maps** to store each attribute.

```
public class Order{
    private int id;
    private Map<String, Integer> num_attribute_map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public Map getNumAttributeMap(){
          return this.num_attribute_map;
    }
```

If an order has `customer_satisfaction` = 5,

```
order_obj.getNumAttributeMap().put("customer_satisfaction" , 5);
```

And thus you have created `Order`s with their attributes stored in the `numAttributeMap`.

---

For implementing a rule on an `Order`

```
$ord : Order(
             getNumAttributeMap[$attribute] >= $value
       )
```

where `$attribute` would be `"customer_satisfaction"`, of course. The `[]` notation is used to access elements of a list, given index or values of a map, given the key.

---

Hope you "get" the concepts of maps. Also, do look up Drools language support for list and map access.

I have also implemented maps of lists of strings to perform an "is in" operation, in addition to maps of integers that do comparison operations. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9241089/604511 too

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep the map solution in mind, unfortunately, it does not give me exactly what I need.