# Property access problems

Tags: drools

I tried to use this rule:

```
rule "conformSyncConstraint"
    when
    $syn_con : SyncConstraint(
        $left_stp_period  : leftSTP.period,
        $right_stp_period : rightSTP.period)
    eval( ($left_stp_period.dayOfWeek == $right_stp_period.dayOfWeek &&
        $left_stp_period.dayOrder == $right_stp_period.dayOrder) == false) 

    then
    insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("conformSyncConstraint", 
        ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_HARD,
        1,
                $syn_con));
end
```

But I face this error, which seemed a blackbox:

```
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='conformSyncConstraint']
    in/co/technovia/timetabler/domain/Rule_conformSyncConstraint_4401252830cd4ee7bc49416ead3da86c.java (8:1459) : The field Period.dayOfWeek is not visible
    in/co/technovia/timetabler/domain/Rule_conformSyncConstraint_4401252830cd4ee7bc49416ead3da86c.java (8:1490) : The field Period.dayOfWeek is not visible


    at org.drools.planner.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildRuleBase(SolverConfig.java:238)
    at org.drools.planner.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:170)
    at org.drools.planner.config.XmlSolverConfigurer.buildSolver(XmlSolverConfigurer.java:103)
    at in.co.technovia.timetabler.TimeTableApp.createSolver(TimeTableApp.java:61)
    at in.co.technovia.timetabler.TimeTableApp.main(TimeTableApp.java:45)
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anytime you use eval, you fallback to the dialect being used. In your case, you are using java dialect, so you have to write the expression with java syntax: .getDayOfWeek() instead of .dayOfWeek.

If you don't use evals, or if you switch the dialect to mvel, you can use the simplified syntax.

E.g.:

```
when
    $syn_con : SyncConstraint(
        leftSTP.period.dayOfWeek != rightSTP.period.dayOfWeek ||
        leftSTP.period.dayOrder != rightSTP.period.dayOrder
    )
then
```

Comment: Could you clarify on when to use eval? I learnt about it [in a question I asked](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Cant-check-complex-boolean-expressions-with-Collections-disjoint-td3842259.html) when [an answer you gave me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9241089/604511) did not work. What did I do wrong then? Im yet to try it: my workday is 12 hours away :-)

Comment: Up to Drools 5.2, you had to use evals() when using a more complex expressions as a constraint, or when your constraint required method calls, because the DRL language did not support those constructs, so eval allowed users to fallback to either Java or MVEL to write down complex constraints. Drools 5.3 improved the support to free form constraints and with 5.4 you basically don't need evals anymore, as any boolean constraint can be written directly. It is important to remember, though, that constraints in the form "<field> <operator> <value>" still have better performance. (continues...)

Comment: (...continuing previous comment) We are working to improve indexing and JITing of more and more complex expressions in 5.4+, but keeping it simple is always better for both the engine and for readability and maintenance of the rules.