# how to iterate nested lists in drl and check for common value across different objects?

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine, drools-kie-server

I have three objects, 
The object BookingSummaryDto has traveller id's

```
public class BookingSummaryDto {    
    private String travellerId;
//getter setters        
}
```

The object BookingSummaryDtoList has the list of BookingSummaryDto objects

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class BookingSummaryDtoList {

    private List<BookingSummaryDto> bookingSummaryDtoList;
}
```

And then the object StayDateGroupingDto has the list of BookingSummaryDtoList objects

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class StayDateGroupingDto {

    List<BookingSummaryDtoList> stayGroupedBookings;

}
```

**The objective is to check for duplicate traveller id's in the StayDateGroupingDto. Which would require iterating the list StayDateGroupingDto to obtain the BookingSummaryDtoList and then iterate it to get BookingSummaryDto object and finally get the traveller id and maintain another list of duplicate traveller id's found.**

***Edit 1***

Here is a raw solution I came up with but I am not sure wether this is the optimal solution and also there are some problems with it.

```
   rule "test data"
    when
        stayDateGroupingIteration : StayDateGroupingDto($stayGroupedBookings : stayGroupedBookings)  
        $travellerCount :Number() from accumulate(BookingSummaryDtoList( $bookingSummaryDtoList : bookingSummaryDtoList) from $stayGroupedBookings,
        init( int count=0;),
        action( 
        for(Object bookingSummary : $bookingSummaryDtoList)
        {


            if(((BookingSummaryDto)bookingSummary).getTravellerId()!=null)
            {   String travellerId=((BookingSummaryDto)bookingSummary).getTravellerId().toString();
                System.out.println(travellerId);
                LoyalityFraudService.checkDuplicates(travellerId);
                count=count+1;
            }
        }
        ),
        result( new Integer(count)))
    then
        System.out.println($travellerCount);
        System.out.println( "clean" );
end
```

The few problems with the above rule are 
how do i put these two initialization in the init block of accumulate

> List globalList=new ArrayList<>();
>           List duplicates=new ArrayList<>();

Or is there another way of handling duplicates across objects?
Also the above rule, is it a good practice to write so much of java code in a drl or should I move some code by calling in some functions. The objective is to keep it as simple so that the business could manage it in future.

Comment: This link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238681/matching-a-list-of-tags-with-another-and-detecting-presence-of-common-elements] might solve your problem.

Comment: @Prog_G the answer you shared is somewhat different. I need to check the presence of common elements in the same dto.Say I have loaded 500 facts(of the same dto) and then I need to see in how many facts the traveller id is same.

Comment: Try using Set instead of List and use collect with the accumulator and then use `set intersection` to find the common element in the Set. `Set<String> s1;
Set<String> s2;
s1.retainAll(s2); // s1 now contains only elements in both sets`

Comment: I have updated the rule. I have solved the problem but want to know that is this the right way of solving it.

Comment: Did you try using set and on that set using retainAll to find the duplicate? I think that is less time-consuming.

Comment: yes set was the obvious choice, the checkDuplicates method uses a set to store duplicates